# CanvasJS Transparent Background

Tags: html, css, canvasjs

I'm trying to add transparency to my CanvasJS background.
CanvasJS uses backgroundColor in order to choose the color of the background of the canvas.

I tried writing "None" instead of a color code but it's giving me a black background.

Also it would be nice to have the ability to choose different opacities for the background.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To set transparent background you can set backgroundColor: "transparent". And if you like to give transparency to any color you can use rgba color coding, for example: backgroundColor: "rgba(225,150,150,0.5)".

Answer (score 1):

You can set `background-color: transparent;` and it will show no color.

Opacity can be set by using rgba. For white 50%, it would be `background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);`

I've never used CanvasJs and don't know how that script will effect things but in basic CSS these will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer eventually. You can just have the backgroundColor with en empty string (backgroundColor:'') and it will omit the background color and leave it transparent.

I would still like to know if it's possible to add transparency to a color, so if anyone knows, please comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
<br/><!-- Just so that JSFiddle's Result label doesn't overlap the Chart -->
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
```

Full demo http://jsfiddle.net/canvasjs/7b0xdcwv/

Answer (score 0):

According to [Canvasjs document](http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-options/title/backgroundcolor/) you will be able to set background color, use rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) for transparent (of course you can change the inside values to fix your purpose):

```
window.onload = function () {
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
    {
      title:{
        text: "Title with Background Color",
        padding: 5,
        backgroundColor: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0),
      },
      data: [
      {
        type: "column",
        dataPoints: [
        { x: 10, y: 71 },
        ]
      }
      ]
    });

    chart.render();
  }
```

Hope this help :)